# Return height for each row in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

How can I return the height for each row in RecycleView? I need it for scrollbar height in RecycleView, like heightForRowAtIndexPath in iOS.
I have the following `RecyclerView.Adapter` for `RecyclerView`.

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String[] items = {"My items"};


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public View mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
    //items = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_text_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((TextView)holder.mTextView.findViewById(R.id.textItemTextView)).setText(items[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}
}
```

But rows have different heights, and scroll change during scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(mRecyclerView.getChildAt(index));
```

Comment: Can I use it for calculate height of all rows and set it value in scroll height?

Comment: What do you mean with "set it value in scroll height"? You can use it to calculate each row height in the RecyclerView.

Comment: But my scroll in RecycleView change height during scrolling. I want to calculate all rows height and change it to scroll height.

Comment: When you talk about "scroll" do you mean the "scroll bar"?

Comment: Yes, I amean scroll bar.

Comment: You can't control that. the scroll bar is based on the compute done over the displayed items (using approximation). Consider what happens if you have a list of +1000 items. You should measure all the items first.

Comment: But how I can fix this bug with change scroll bar durint scrolling?

Comment: From the best of my knowledge, the only possibility is to have all the rows with the same height.

Comment: Ohh, I do not know how to make it beautiful for android.

Comment: You can use a ScrollView instead, but this depends on how many data you have in your list, and if they are dynamic.

Comment: If I have slight differences in height of the cells, I have to use CardView?